# Dynamic length of rows for Twitter-Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating mockup where the content will look like a board, a little like Pinterest. I am using Twitters-Bootstrap, and are having some issues with the layout.

I have a dynamic amount of elements, so I thought I could just have one row, and the items would then just wrap to the next line. This, however, creates som wierd space between the content-spans (see image below).

I am not a designer, so my question is, if there is a way to use one single row to display all the content blocks, still using the fluid design?

Another way would be to programmatically add the rows, but it seems like a problem which the stylesheet and not business logic should solve.

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <li class="span3 pdt10">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5>
                        Thumbnail label</h5>
                    <p>
                        Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi
                        porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3 pdt10">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5>
                        Thumbnail label</h5>
                    <p>
                        Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi
                        porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3 pdt10">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5>
                        Thumbnail label</h5>
                    <p>
                        Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi
                        porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3 pdt10">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5>
                        Thumbnail label</h5>
                    <p>
                        Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi
                        porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="span3 pdt10">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5>
                        Thumbnail label</h5>
                    <p>
                        Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi
                        porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Action</a> <a href="#" class="btn">Action</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the CSS property nth-child with media queries to remove the left margin on the first element of each line -

```
.myclass > li:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Media queries are explained here http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

And nth-child is used in Twitter Bootstrap as well.

Comment: Thanks, it could be done like this: .myclass > li:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 0px;
}